# Using wildcards in HAVING

Tags: sql

Im trying to get a list of all the countries that have atleast 2 customers with yahoo email.

So far I came up with this:

```
SELECT Country 
FROM Customer
GROUP BY Country
HAVING COUNT(Email LIKE '%yahoo%')>= 2
```

This doesnt work though. Probably because I cant use LIKE in HAVING clause. I tried to use it in where clause, but I cant use aggregate functions there. Do you know how to make this work? Assume standard sql. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Country 
FROM Customer 
GROUP BY Country 
HAVING SUM(case when Email like '%yahoo%' then 1 else 0 end )>= 2
```

Or just put the limit in your where clause...  This way the limit is imposed before the count possibly having a performance boost; since it only has to evaluate the emails that are like '%yahoo%' instead or all emails when counting; but since the where clause has to do the evaluation 1st anyway.  I'm not sure which would be faster w/o testing.

```
SELECT Country 
FROM Customer 
WHERE email like '%yahoo%'
GROUP BY Country 
HAVING count(Email)>= 2
```

though like %val% is unable to use any index so; maybe not. but if it was like %yahoo.com' you'd see one. (if index is on email)

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to build your aggregated list of filtered countries.

SETUP TEST DATA

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#td', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #td; 

CREATE TABLE #td ( country varchar(10), email varchar(20) ) ;

INSERT INTO #td ( country, email )
VALUES 
       ('US','bob@builder.com')
     , ('GB','bob@yahoo.com')
     , ('US','bill@yahoo.com')
     , ('US','ted@yahoo.com')
     , ('FR','joe@friday.com')
     , ('GR','jim@gmail.com')
     , ('NZ','mrmaori@yahoo.com')
     , ('NZ','kiwi@yahoo.com')    
     , ('US','rufus@yahoo.com')
;
```

QUERY

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT country, count(*) AS countryCount
   FROM #td
   WHERE email LIKE '%yahoo%'
   GROUP BY country
)
SELECT CTE.country
FROM CTE 
WHERE CTE.countryCount >= 2
;
```

This will give you NZ and US as the only 2 countries. US has 3 yahoo and 1 non-yahoo. NZ has 2 yahoo. GB has only 1 yahoo and is excluded.

Comment: I tested this query and the two above by xQbert. I duplicated my 9 temp table rows 100000 times for almost a million rows. All 3 ran pretty quickly, but my CTE and xQbert's HAVING...COUNT() query created the same plan and ran in the same time. The other query (HAVING...sum(CASE...))) ran only slightly longer with a similar plan in a slightly different order with the scalar sum() running on all 900k rows (probably the time difference). I think it would take a ginormous data set to really see a significant difference, though the CTE and HAVING...COUNT() options seem to be fastest.